# Generating text for resource files

Tags: c#, asp.net, resource-files

I'm trying to generate text that looks like the following:

> [Åđđřęşş Ŀįŉę 1 !!! !!!]

I want this for my default resource file so I can easily identify when a translation is missing.

I'm sure this kind of text generation must have a name that I just don't as the closest thing I could find is [String.Normalize](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ebza6ck1(v=vs.110).aspx) which is the reverse of what I'm after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The term you are looking for is Pseudointernationalization.

Some resources:

- https://github.com/shanselman/Psuedoizer
- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/GlobalizationInternationalizationAndLocalizationInASPNETMVC3JavaScriptAndJQueryPart1.aspx

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for. Rep++

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables: I made that same assumption too, but the answer is accurate I believe.

Comment: Why downvote? I believe that the question was asking the name of such a method, which in this case is Pseudointernationalization ...

Comment: @PatrickHofman - yeah, I can see your point.  The links in the answer are usually a no-no, though, and that tripped me up.